# Remotely working from France for a US company

Tags: united-states, france

I'm French, I live in France and I'm considering applying for a remote job in a US company. Are there any legal issues that would prevent me to do so? How would the time spent working in a US company affect my future retirement plan? What about the things any French employer contributes to such as "*la sécurité sociale*"? Can I lose some benefits in France by paying my taxes to the US? Are there any tricky things I should know about this situation?

Comment: I don't know about France, but in the UK (most) income from overseas is liable for tax in the UK as this is where it is earned - I assume this will be a standard approach across the EU but a suitably qualified accountant should be able to advise.

Comment: Sorry, I migrated this but I shouldn’t have. I can’t undo it. If you want to post this question again, I will delete this one.