# Remotely working from France for a US company (repost asked by mod)

Tags: united-states, france

I'm French, I live in France and I'm considering applying for a remote job in a US company. Are there any legal issues that would prevent me to do so? How would the time spent working in a US company affect my future retirement plan? What about the things any French employer contributes to such as "la sécurité sociale"? Can I lose some benefits in France by paying my taxes to the US? Are there any tricky things I should know about this situation?

Repost asked by [Remotely working from France for a US company](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/61687/remotely-working-from-france-for-a-us-company#comment129315_61687)

Comment: I don't know about France, but in the UK (most) income from overseas is liable for tax in the UK as this is where it is earned - I assume this will be a standard approach across the EU but a suitably qualified accountant should be able to advise.